# realloc() not allocating after first call

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, realloc

I keep getting segmentation faults (I know what that means I just don't understand why I keep getting them).

```
int main(void)
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  int cardsSize = 0; //tracks the amount of memory space my pointer is pointing too.
  int *cards = NULL; 

  if(drawCard(&cards, ++cardsSize) == -1)
  {
      printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
      return 0;
  }

  if(drawCard(&cards, ++cardsSize) == -1)
  {
      printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
      return 0;
  }
//... more code
}
```

The part where `realloc()` gets called:

```
int drawCard(int **cardsptr, int cardsSize)
{
  int newCard = rand() % 13;

  printf("Address before:\t%p\ncardsSize:\t%d\n", *cardsptr, cardsSize); //an attempt at debugging by examining if the null pointer actually gets an address.

  *cardsptr = realloc(*cardsptr, cardsSize * sizeof(int));

  printf("Address after:\t%p\n", *cardsptr); 

  if(*cardsptr == NULL)
    return -1;

  if (newCard > 10)
    **(cardsptr + cardsSize - 1) = 10;
  else
    **(cardsptr + cardsSize - 1) = newCard;

  printf("Reached.\n"); //to see if I crash before or after trying to assign a value.
  return 0;
}
```

The first time `drawCard()` is called everything works fine. The second time I get a segmentation fault error as soon as I want to assign a value to the newly allocated memory.

The output of the debug messages are:

```
Address before: (nil)
cardsSize:  1
Address after:  0x2428010
Reached.

Address before: 0x2428010
cardsSize:  2
Address after:  0x2428010
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

To my knowledge it should work.
I pass a pointer to a `NULL` pointer to the `drawCard()` function and dereference it when calling `realloc()`. This makes `realloc()` act like `malloc()` which also ensures that that pointer can be passed to `realloc()` in the future as `realloc()` requires a pointer that points to memory that was allocated by `malloc()`.
I keep track of the size through `cardsSize` and use that in combination with `sizeof` to reallocate the right amount of memory. I check to see if `realloc()` succeeded by checking to see if it returned a `NULL` pointer.
Then I dereference it twice so I can put a value in one of the memory spots my initial pointer is now pointing too.

Comment: `**(cardsptr + cardsSize - 1) =`. For hreater good and plolonged state of sanity use square brackets. Do you have an array? Use it like an array.

Comment: If `realloc` fails, the original block is unchanged. You, however, overwrite the pointer with the result of `realloc`, thus loosing the original block. This is a memory leak. You also don't free the blocks you allocate. Bad style here, but trouble in many other programs. Get the habit of doing it right in small code, so you will do it right where vital.

Comment: @Olaf used a temporary pointer to receive realloc()  and free() wherever needed now. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `**(cardsptr + cardsSize - 1)`.

You add `cardsSize - 1` to the pointer to the `cards` variable. `cardsptr` points to something in the stack. So adding `cardsSize - 1` to it moves you to something in the stack you apparently can't dereference – and didn't intend to dereference.

So either use `*(*cardsptr + cardsSize - 1)` or less obscure `(*cardsptr)[cardsSize - 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

`**(cardsptr + cardsSize - 1)` should be changed into `*(*cardsptr + cardSize - 1)`, or to be more intuitive, `(*cardsptr)[cardSize-1]`.